mouse pointer cycling through all icons rapidly
On my windows 10 system, suddenly, my mouse has started cycling through all of the mouse icons...
For example, it'll go from the regular pointer, to the text icon, to the "scrolling" icon, to the info icon, non-stop, to where it is extremely difficult to tell where the actual pointer is.
i have tried re-installing drivers. I have tried buying a new mouse or 2! I have tried resetting the colors, the size, the scroll speed, and the trails setting.

Is your GPU nVidia? Try reinstalling GPU drivers.

Have you tried rebooting?
